# Unable to type value to invisible grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, cypress

I'm having trouble focusing on an element in the search grid. I've targeted it now, but I can't write anything in it. It doesn't make a mistake, it just doesn't write the characters of "St". Anyone have an idea what I'm doing wrong? Could the problem be that the element is not visible?

Code in Cypress:

```
cy.get('div[id="grid"]').find('.dx-datagrid-filter-row')
  .find(".dx-editor-with-menu").eq(2)cy.focused().click({ force: true }).type('St');
```

Evaluation:

[image: Evaluation in Cypress]

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like:

```js
cy.get('div[id="grid"]')
  .find('.dx-editor-with-menu')
  .eq(2)
  .focus()
  .click({force: true})
  .type('St', {force: true})
```

Comment: at final was good this, but with different scope.


   cy.get('div[id="grid"]')
        .find('.dx-texteditor-input')
        .eq(2)
        .type('St', {force: true})